# curl json replacing 'sect' to section sign in url

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a little problem. My code:

```
 <?php 
$url = "http://xxxx/duplicate";

$data = array (
userId                          =>      xxxx, // authentication userId
loginToken                      =>      'xxxx', // authentication loginToken
 "id"                            =>      "123456",
 'section'                       =>      'LotRental',

);
 $data_string = http_build_query($data);
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch); 
 print_r ($result);
echo json_encode($data_string);
?>
```

but it creates this post:

```
userId=xxxx&loginToken=xxxx&id=123456§ion=LotRental
```

it changes "section" to "§ion"

request shoud look like:

```
userId=xxxx&loginToken=xxxx&id=123456&section=LotRental
```

how to fix it? 
Thanks

update:

I can duplicate my item by two ways: this curl above or just type url in browser

when I execute my php script I'm getting error from a serwer:

```
HTTP ERROR: 405

METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
RequestURI=xxxx/duplicate.dispatch
```

But when I type in browser

```
http://xxxx/duplicate?userId=xxxx&loginToken=xxxx&id=123456&section=LotRental
```

it works fine

Comment: How are you checking the POST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script itself is OK wrt. to its output. It looks like you're viewing the output of this script in a browser. You must then properly HTML-encode the output before sending it to the browser, but instead you seem to JSON-encode it. So instead of:

```
echo json_encode($data_string);
```

you would use:

```
echo htmlentities($data_string);
```

Comment: Your browser example suggests that you need HTTP  GET instead of POST.